# bind ImageView to WebView (when scrolling)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-webview, android-imageview

Within my android application I have a "main" `Webview`. On top of this `WebView` I want to use an `ImageView`. The (sample) application looks as follows:

[image: ImageView on top of a Webview]

The `WebView` (big android logo) is scrollable/zoomable. My goal is that the `ImageView` (small icon) automatically scrolls (but not zooms) **with** the `WebView`. It should stay on the same position of the android logo. Its basically the Google Maps "My Location" pinpoint behaviour:

[image: google maps pinpoint]

It would be great if somebody could point me in a right direction or give some good advices (maybe the right listener for the `WebView`).

**Note:** Yes I have to use a `WebView` because I'm going to load a .gif file.

My (simplified) code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView wv = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.mainWebView);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);           
    wv.loadUrl("http://www.myurl.com/android.gif");
}
```

The omitted layout .xml file just contains a `WebView` and an `ImageView`.

Comment: Did you find the solution ? @domi